# How to subscribe to angularMaterial Dialog afterClosed?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Regarding closing a dialog. https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog `afterClosed` is not thenable?

As in official main documentation:

[image]

#### Error

`Property 'then' does not exist on type '() => Observable<any>'. [default] Checking finished with 1 errors`

I tried subscribe, but doesnt work either.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Based **on the examples part** of their [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog)

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogResultExampleDialog);

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  this.selectedOption = result;
});
```

But you always can convert result to promise if needed

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().toPromise()
```

Do not forget to add `toPromise` support

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";
```

Comment: Are we looking at the same documentation? In my version (I screenshotted it) I see `.then`. From which docs do you have the `.subscribe` ?

Comment: Yes, open examles tab. Here you can find working example

Comment: Thanks! Bonus: How to unsubscribe in this case, if using this subscription?

Comment: try this: `let subscription = dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(); subscription.unsubscribe();`

Comment: Should the unsubscription be called immediately or onDestroy()?

Comment: It looks like in this case, the Observable is a "finite observable" (`.next()` is called on it, and `.complete()` right after that), so we shouldn't need to unsubscribe, according to https://netbasal.com/when-to-unsubscribe-in-angular-d61c6b21bad3

Answer (score 49):

No need to unsubscribe from `afterClosed()` as it auto completes itself:
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/ae41a0ad69ca26c600f0f56c68dd5a1c102d4f1f/src/lib/dialog/dialog-ref.ts#L75

Comment: :-) It works because it does this `this._afterClosed.next(this._result); this._afterClosed.complete();`

Comment: THIS should be the accepted answer. @VladimirB's answer is just not correct.

Comment: What if they ever change the behaviour of afterClosed not to complete when the modal is closed. how likely that would be. Wouldn't that be better to have a safety net and unsubscribe in your code anyway?

Answer (score 17):

https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog

**afterClosed** method returns an **Observable** so it is not thenable like **Promise** object.

To avoid using **toPromise** method on the **Observable** you can use **take(1)** to unsubscribe **automatically** after the first event:

```js
dialogRef.afterClosed().take(1).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`); // Pizza!
});
```

Comment: not necessary to unsubscribe. while internally a `Subject<R>` it completes immediately `this._afterClosed.next(this._result); this._afterClosed.complete();` so therefore `take(1)` does nothing useful - but in general a good practice and does no harm if you're ever not sure!

Comment: Depending on your UI/UX design, it might be possible that the dialog remains active while the underlying component has been switched.  Without unsubscribing after the component 1 had gone, the dialog created in component may continue to execute the handling when the component is in place now. You may or may not want such workflow. If you don't want, then unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy of component 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the first() RxJs operator instead of take(1). For my personal opinion it looks better (although they do the same).

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().first().subscribe(result => {
console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
});
```

Comment: first() and take(1) don't do the same

Comment: You are correct my friend. Its better to use take(1). Thumbs up